# MVC - How many responsibilities should a model possess?

Tags: model-view-controller, models

I'm learning MVC (and indeed OOP) and finding the examples online great for basic overview but when I get into the nuts and bolts of a complex project I'm coming a bit unstuck.

I've setout a basic 'User' model below.  What I'm wondering is at what point does a Model have too many responsibilities? And when this happens what are the options?  Should you have sub models - e.g. UserLoginModel instead of an all encompassing User Model?

PS cannot seem to paste the code so it will all stay in code block - sorry about that.

```
//USER MODEL
```

class UserModel 
{

```
private $userId;

private $userName;

private $address

private $email

private $password;

/**
* Some instance of a DB class
*/
private $db;

/**
* Some encryption class which can generate cipher text
*/
private $encryption;

public function __construct($databaseClass){

    //some database layer like a table gateway
    $this->db = $databaseClass;

    //some encryption class which can be used to test a password against a cipher
    $this->enc = $encryptionClass;
}

/*
    GETTERS/SETTERS...  
*/


public function findUser($username){

    // 1. Find user in database
    // 2. Map database array to properties
    // 3. Return boolean
}

public function validateLogin($password){

    // 1. Turn $pasword into cipher text using $this->enc class
    // 2. Match User object password
    // 3. Return boolean
}


public function updateUser($data){
    //some code for updating the user
}

public function deleteUser($user){
    //code for deleting user
}
```

}

//Authentication controller - receives request /AuthController/doLogin

class AuthController
{

```
public function doLogin(){

    $db = new databaseClass(); //e.g. a tablegateway
    $encryptionClass = new encryptionClass(); //some class which generates ciphers 

    $user = new UserModel($db);
    if($user->findUser($_POST['username'])){

        $loginSuccess = $user->validateLogin($_POST['password']);
        //do stuff 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is the central component of the design pattern. It expresses the application's behavior in terms of the problem domain, independent of the user interface. It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.

All the functions and responsibilities must have in Model.

The Controller accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view. It will get the function and/or methods by the Model.

And the View can be any output representation of information, or input of data by user.

[Example of MVC Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5U5K.jpg)

StudentView will be a view class which can print student details on console and StudentController is the controller class responsible to store data in Student object and update view StudentView accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. So does a Model therefore not necessarily need to adhere to Single Responsibility Principle? And therefore you can have one super model for a user instead of multiple small focused models for a user e.g. UserLoginModel, UserPostArticleModel??

Comment: You have one model for the application. If it is complex, e.g. a car sim in a racing game, it has sub-components like the clutch, the speedometer, and so on, which often could be abstracted out as models in their own right. But it's one model. If you have several cars in the sim, it's still one model, of a "race", with the separate cars merely the most obvious division of components.

Comment: Thanks Malcom.  So if you do have a complex model and separate out the clutch, speedometer from the Car is it common practice to compose the Car with those sub models?  I realise this is very abstract and subjective.  I'm just confused about complex models and I don't have a real life example to refer to.

Comment: The programmer defines how the architecture of system must be. In a race, if you have cars with same characteristics, you have one model 'Car', but if you have to do cars with different characteristics (like trucks and bikes), or cars with complex characteristics (like clutch and speedometer) you must do models to all these objects.